# Count results from mongo aggregate method

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to count results from mongo shell aggregate method?

Is there a simpler way than adding

> {$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:1}}}

to the query?

For example I have following schema:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("541b2b6813e401118fcf9ec6"),
        "customer" : "Bob",
        "items" : [
                "pear",
                "apple"
        ]
}
```

And I want to count how many pears has Bob ordered (he had multiple orders, and items can contain duplicates). I came with following query:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
            "customer": {
                $eq: "Bob"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$items"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "items": {
                $eq: "pear"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
]
)
```

With response:

```
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 1 }
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: If the items would not contain duplicates, we could use find query like: db.orders.find({"customer" : "Bob","items":"pear"}).count() to get the result without using aggregation...

Comment: Well yes that is true. So the question is do you just want to count the documents that match your condition or do you want to count the occurrences of that condition where there are duplicates? This is the essential difference in the two forms.

Comment: @NeilLunn Forget about the example. I just want to count returned documents from aggregate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I found 2 different similar stackoverflow questions:

- [MongoDB - Aggregation Framework (Total Count)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767580/mongodb-aggregation-framework-total-count)
- [Mongo aggregation cursor & counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239408/mongo-aggregation-cursor-counting)

and it looks this is not possible to count the results without mentioned grouping.