# Why is PyMongo count_documents is slower than count?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

In `db['TF']` I have about 60 million records.

I need to get the quantity of the records.

If I run `db['TF'].count()`, it returns at once.

If I run `db['TF'].count_documents({})`, that is a such long time before I get the result.

However, the `count` method will be deprecated.

So, how can I get the quantity quickly when using `count_documents`? Is there some arguments I missed?

I have read the doc and code, but nothing found.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not about PyMongo but Mongo itself.

`count` is a native Mongo function. It doesn't really count all the documents. Whenever you insert or delete a record in Mongo, it caches the total number of records in the collection. Then when you run `count`, Mongo will return that cached value.

`count_documents` uses a query object, which means that it has to loop through all the records in order to get the total count. Because you're not passing any parameters, it will have to run over all 60 million records. This is why it is slow.

based on @Stennie comment

> You can use estimated_document_count() in PyMongo 3.7+ to return the fast count based on collection metadata. The original count() was deprecated because the behaviour differed (estimated vs actual count) based on whether query criteria was provided. The newer driver API is more intentional about the outcome

Comment: so the ```count_documents``` is not suitable for this situation.  and I should use ```count``` method or call the native mongo function by myself, right?

Comment: well you can try use count_documents without any params any see if it works as well

Comment: so please upvote and accept the answer this is what we do here in stackoverflow (:

Comment: So why is count() being deprecated according to pymongo?  count_documents() takes way to long to run on large datasets.

Comment: @jschmitter You can use [`estimated_data_count()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.estimated_document_count) in PyMongo 3.7+ to return the fast count based on collection metadata. The original `count()` was deprecated because the behaviour differed (estimated vs actual count) based on whether query criteria was provided. The newer driver API is more intentional about the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52236791/3100115), the behavior is not specific to PyMongo.

The reason is because the [`count_documents`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) method in PyMongo performs an aggregation query and does not use any metadata. see [collection.py#L1670-L1688](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/341b2b5964b246fe7419a812e31b84e023c7c030/pymongo/collection.py#L1670-L1688)

```
pipeline = [{'$match': filter}]
if 'skip' in kwargs:
    pipeline.append({'$skip': kwargs.pop('skip')})
if 'limit' in kwargs:
    pipeline.append({'$limit': kwargs.pop('limit')})
pipeline.append({'$group': {'_id': None, 'n': {'$sum': 1}}})
cmd = SON([('aggregate', self.__name),
           ('pipeline', pipeline),
           ('cursor', {})])
if "hint" in kwargs and not isinstance(kwargs["hint"], string_type):
    kwargs["hint"] = helpers._index_document(kwargs["hint"])
collation = validate_collation_or_none(kwargs.pop('collation', None))
cmd.update(kwargs)
with self._socket_for_reads(session) as (sock_info, slave_ok):
    result = self._aggregate_one_result(
        sock_info, slave_ok, cmd, collation, session)
if not result:
    return 0
return result['n']
```

This command has the same [behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#mechanics) as the [`collection.countDocuments`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) method.

That being said, if you willing to trade accuracy for performance, you can use the [`estimated_document_count`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.estimated_document_count) method which on the other hand, send a [`count`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/count/#dbcmd.count) command to the database with the same [behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/#behavior) as [`collection.estimatedDocumentCount`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/) See [collection.py#L1609-L1614](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/341b2b5964b246fe7419a812e31b84e023c7c030/pymongo/collection.py#L1609-L1614)

```
if 'session' in kwargs:
    raise ConfigurationError(
        'estimated_document_count does not support sessions')
    cmd = SON([('count', self.__name)])
    cmd.update(kwargs)
    return self._count(cmd)
```

Where [`self._count`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/341b2b5964b246fe7419a812e31b84e023c7c030/pymongo/collection.py#L1561-L1575) *is a helper* sending the command.